# dont know how to position SVG icon coordinates from a SVG file

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a sprite file that I wish to display from the CSS file, but I dont know how to set the coordinates correctly, or how to display them.

I wish to use a toggle link, that changes the icon based off the coordinates like my code below shows, however I dont know how to attach the sprite file in here for it work, but I have added the sprite file below to a separate snippet below...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="267.125px" height="74px" viewBox="0 0 267.125 74" enable-background="new 0 0 267.125 74" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M64.246,0C54.302,0,46.24,8.062,46.24,18.006c0,9.946,8.062,18.006,18.006,18.006
  c9.945,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C82.252,8.062,74.191,0,64.246,0z M68.104,18.013H65.58c0,4.031,0,8.996,0,8.996h-3.739
  c0,0,0-4.915,0-8.996h-1.778v-3.178h1.778v-2.057c0-1.473,0.699-3.774,3.773-3.774l2.77,0.011V12.1c0,0-1.684,0-2.01,0
  c-0.327,0-0.793,0.163-0.793,0.866v1.868h2.851L68.104,18.013z" />
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M110.258,0c-9.944,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.062,18.006,18.006,18.006
  s18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C128.264,8.062,120.202,0,110.258,0z M117.418,14.335c0.008,0.158,0.011,0.317,0.011,0.477
  c0,4.882-3.716,10.511-10.511,10.511c-2.087,0-4.028-0.611-5.663-1.659c0.29,0.033,0.584,0.051,0.881,0.051
  c1.732,0,3.323-0.589,4.587-1.58c-1.616-0.031-2.981-1.099-3.45-2.565c0.225,0.042,0.456,0.066,0.694,0.066
  c0.337,0,0.664-0.046,0.973-0.13c-1.688-0.341-2.963-1.833-2.963-3.622c0-0.015,0-0.031,0-0.046
  c0.499,0.277,1.068,0.442,1.674,0.462c-0.991-0.662-1.643-1.794-1.643-3.075c0-0.677,0.182-1.312,0.5-1.857
  c1.821,2.235,4.544,3.706,7.614,3.86c-0.063-0.27-0.096-0.552-0.096-0.842c0-2.04,1.654-3.693,3.695-3.693
  c1.062,0,2.022,0.448,2.696,1.165c0.841-0.165,1.632-0.473,2.346-0.897c-0.277,0.864-0.862,1.587-1.624,2.044
  c0.747-0.088,1.46-0.288,2.121-0.58C118.767,13.164,118.14,13.814,117.418,14.335z" />
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M157.35,16.683v-0.037c-0.007,0.013-0.017,0.026-0.025,0.037H157.35z" />
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M156.27,0c-9.945,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.061,18.006,18.006,18.006
    c9.944,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C174.277,8.062,166.214,0,156.27,0z M151.356,26.611h-3.861v-11.61h3.861L151.356,26.611
    L151.356,26.611z M149.425,13.415H149.4c-1.295,0-2.132-0.892-2.132-2.007c0-1.139,0.864-2.007,2.183-2.007
    c1.321,0,2.134,0.868,2.158,2.007C151.608,12.522,150.771,13.415,149.425,13.415z M165.273,26.611h-3.86V20.4
    c0-1.561-0.558-2.627-1.956-2.627c-1.065,0-1.701,0.721-1.98,1.413c-0.102,0.248-0.128,0.591-0.128,0.941v6.484h-3.859
    c0,0,0.049-10.522,0-11.61h3.859v1.644c0.514-0.794,1.431-1.917,3.479-1.917c2.539,0,4.444,1.657,4.444,5.225L165.273,26.611
    L165.273,26.611z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <ellipse fill="#FFFFFF" cx="202.3" cy="18.195" rx="3.606" ry="3.494" />
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M207.881,18.391c0,2.985-2.499,5.406-5.581,5.406c-3.081,0-5.581-2.421-5.581-5.406
    c0-0.536,0.082-1.052,0.231-1.541h-1.648v7.584c0,0.393,0.321,0.712,0.713,0.712h12.501c0.393,0,0.713-0.319,0.713-0.712V16.85
    h-1.579C207.8,17.338,207.881,17.854,207.881,18.391z" />
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M206.385,14.803h2.029c0.444,0,0.808-0.364,0.808-0.809V12.06c0-0.445-0.364-0.809-0.808-0.809h-2.029
    c-0.445,0-0.809,0.364-0.809,0.809v1.934C205.576,14.44,205.939,14.803,206.385,14.803z" />
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M202.283,0.227c-9.945,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.061,18.006,18.006,18.006
    c9.944,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C220.289,8.29,212.226,0.227,202.283,0.227z M211.259,24.906c0,1.267-1.037,2.303-2.304,2.303
    h-13.343c-1.268,0-2.305-1.036-2.305-2.303V11.562c0-1.268,1.037-2.304,2.305-2.304h13.343c1.267,0,2.304,1.037,2.304,2.304
    V24.906z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M18.12,0C8.113,0,0,8.113,0,18.12c0,10.009,8.113,18.12,18.12,18.12s18.12-8.111,18.12-18.12
  C36.24,8.113,28.127,0,18.12,0z M19.991,22.155c-1.124,0-2.181-0.606-2.543-1.296c0,0-0.605,2.398-0.732,2.86
  c-0.451,1.637-1.777,3.274-1.879,3.406c-0.072,0.093-0.231,0.064-0.248-0.06c-0.029-0.208-0.367-2.272,0.031-3.955
  c0.2-0.845,1.339-5.671,1.339-5.671s-0.333-0.664-0.333-1.646c0-1.544,0.895-2.694,2.008-2.694c0.947,0,1.402,0.71,1.402,1.562
  c0,0.951-0.605,2.376-0.918,3.694c-0.261,1.104,0.553,2.004,1.642,2.004c1.972,0,3.3-2.533,3.3-5.534
  c0-2.281-1.536-3.988-4.331-3.988c-3.156,0-5.124,2.356-5.124,4.986c0,0.907,0.268,1.546,0.687,2.039
  c0.192,0.228,0.219,0.321,0.149,0.582c-0.051,0.19-0.164,0.653-0.212,0.834c-0.069,0.265-0.283,0.358-0.521,0.261
  c-1.454-0.593-2.131-2.185-2.131-3.977c0-2.955,2.493-6.501,7.439-6.501c3.974,0,6.589,2.876,6.589,5.963
  C25.607,19.104,23.337,22.155,19.991,22.155z" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M64.246,36.38c-9.944,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.062,18.006,18.006,18.006
  c9.945,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C82.252,44.442,74.191,36.38,64.246,36.38z M68.104,54.393H65.58c0,4.031,0,8.996,0,8.996
  h-3.739c0,0,0-4.915,0-8.996h-1.778v-3.178h1.778v-2.057c0-1.473,0.699-3.774,3.773-3.774l2.77,0.011v3.085c0,0-1.684,0-2.01,0
  c-0.327,0-0.793,0.163-0.793,0.866v1.868h2.851L68.104,54.393z" />
    <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M110.258,36.38c-9.944,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.062,18.006,18.006,18.006
  s18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C128.264,44.442,120.202,36.38,110.258,36.38z M117.418,50.715c0.008,0.158,0.011,0.317,0.011,0.477
  c0,4.882-3.716,10.511-10.511,10.511c-2.087,0-4.028-0.611-5.663-1.659c0.29,0.033,0.584,0.051,0.881,0.051
  c1.732,0,3.323-0.589,4.587-1.58c-1.616-0.031-2.981-1.099-3.45-2.565c0.225,0.042,0.456,0.066,0.694,0.066
  c0.337,0,0.664-0.046,0.973-0.13c-1.688-0.341-2.963-1.833-2.963-3.622c0-0.015,0-0.031,0-0.046
  c0.499,0.277,1.068,0.442,1.674,0.462c-0.991-0.662-1.643-1.794-1.643-3.075c0-0.677,0.182-1.312,0.5-1.857
  c1.821,2.235,4.544,3.706,7.614,3.86c-0.063-0.27-0.096-0.552-0.096-0.842c0-2.04,1.654-3.693,3.695-3.693
  c1.062,0,2.022,0.448,2.696,1.165c0.841-0.165,1.632-0.473,2.346-0.897c-0.277,0.864-0.862,1.587-1.624,2.044
  c0.747-0.088,1.46-0.288,2.121-0.58C118.767,49.544,118.14,50.194,117.418,50.715z" />
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M157.35,53.063v-0.037c-0.007,0.013-0.017,0.026-0.025,0.037H157.35z" />
        <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M156.27,36.38c-9.945,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.061,18.006,18.006,18.006
    c9.944,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C174.277,44.442,166.214,36.38,156.27,36.38z M151.356,62.991h-3.861v-11.61h3.861
    L151.356,62.991L151.356,62.991z M149.425,49.795H149.4c-1.295,0-2.132-0.892-2.132-2.007c0-1.139,0.864-2.007,2.183-2.007
    c1.321,0,2.134,0.868,2.158,2.007C151.608,48.902,150.771,49.795,149.425,49.795z M165.273,62.991h-3.86V56.78
    c0-1.561-0.558-2.627-1.956-2.627c-1.065,0-1.701,0.721-1.98,1.413c-0.102,0.248-0.128,0.591-0.128,0.941v6.484h-3.859
    c0,0,0.049-10.522,0-11.61h3.859v1.644c0.514-0.794,1.431-1.917,3.479-1.917c2.539,0,4.444,1.657,4.444,5.225L165.273,62.991
    L165.273,62.991z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <ellipse fill="#28A9E1" cx="202.3" cy="54.575" rx="3.606" ry="3.494" />
        <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M207.881,54.771c0,2.985-2.499,5.406-5.581,5.406c-3.081,0-5.581-2.421-5.581-5.406
    c0-0.536,0.082-1.052,0.231-1.541h-1.648v7.584c0,0.393,0.321,0.712,0.713,0.712h12.501c0.393,0,0.713-0.319,0.713-0.712V53.23
    h-1.579C207.8,53.718,207.881,54.234,207.881,54.771z" />
        <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M206.385,51.183h2.029c0.444,0,0.808-0.364,0.808-0.809V48.44c0-0.445-0.364-0.809-0.808-0.809h-2.029
    c-0.445,0-0.809,0.364-0.809,0.809v1.934C205.576,50.82,205.939,51.183,206.385,51.183z" />
        <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M202.283,36.607c-9.945,0-18.006,8.062-18.006,18.006c0,9.946,8.061,18.006,18.006,18.006
    c9.944,0,18.006-8.06,18.006-18.006C220.289,44.67,212.226,36.607,202.283,36.607z M211.259,61.286
    c0,1.267-1.037,2.303-2.304,2.303h-13.343c-1.268,0-2.305-1.036-2.305-2.303V47.942c0-1.268,1.037-2.304,2.305-2.304h13.343
    c1.267,0,2.304,1.037,2.304,2.304V61.286z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M18.12,36.38C8.113,36.38,0,44.493,0,54.5c0,10.009,8.113,18.12,18.12,18.12s18.12-8.111,18.12-18.12
  C36.24,44.493,28.127,36.38,18.12,36.38z M19.991,58.535c-1.124,0-2.181-0.606-2.543-1.296c0,0-0.605,2.398-0.732,2.86
  c-0.451,1.637-1.777,3.274-1.879,3.406c-0.072,0.093-0.231,0.064-0.248-0.06c-0.029-0.208-0.367-2.272,0.031-3.955
  c0.2-0.845,1.339-5.671,1.339-5.671s-0.333-0.664-0.333-1.646c0-1.544,0.895-2.694,2.008-2.694c0.947,0,1.402,0.71,1.402,1.562
  c0,0.951-0.605,2.376-0.918,3.694c-0.261,1.104,0.553,2.004,1.642,2.004c1.972,0,3.3-2.533,3.3-5.534
  c0-2.281-1.536-3.988-4.331-3.988c-3.156,0-5.124,2.356-5.124,4.986c0,0.907,0.268,1.546,0.687,2.039
  c0.192,0.228,0.219,0.321,0.149,0.582c-0.051,0.19-0.164,0.653-0.212,0.834c-0.069,0.265-0.283,0.358-0.521,0.261
  c-1.454-0.593-2.131-2.185-2.131-3.977c0-2.955,2.493-6.501,7.439-6.501c3.974,0,6.589,2.876,6.589,5.963
  C25.607,55.484,23.337,58.535,19.991,58.535z" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M248.119,1.293c9.252,0,16.812,7.461,16.812,16.713s-7.561,16.812-16.812,16.812
  c-9.252,0-16.713-7.561-16.713-16.812S238.868,1.293,248.119,1.293 M248.119,0c-9.948,0-18.006,8.058-18.006,18.006
  s8.058,18.006,18.006,18.006c9.948,0,18.006-8.058,18.006-18.006S258.067,0,248.119,0L248.119,0z" />
    <g>
      <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="236.381,14.624 236.381,20.99 240.559,16.315   " />
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M255.381,16.613v-1.99l-4.178,1.592l1.293,1.393C253.292,17.111,254.287,16.713,255.381,16.613z" />
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M251.402,18.503l-1.592-1.691l-4.079,1.592l-3.88-1.592l-5.471,6.168v0.398h13.33c0-0.199,0-0.398,0-0.497
   C249.612,21.189,250.308,19.598,251.402,18.503z" />
      <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="244.936,16.713 245.732,16.912 246.627,16.713 250.208,15.32 255.381,13.33 255.381,11.54 
   236.381,11.54 236.381,13.231 241.454,15.32   " />
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M260.952,21.587c-0.099-0.298-0.199-0.597-0.298-0.895c-0.696-1.492-2.189-2.487-3.979-2.686
   c-0.199,0-0.398-0.099-0.597-0.099l0,0c-0.199,0-0.398,0-0.597,0.099c-0.796,0.099-1.492,0.298-2.089,0.696
   c-0.199,0.099-0.398,0.199-0.497,0.398c-0.199,0.099-0.298,0.298-0.497,0.398c-0.199,0.199-0.398,0.398-0.597,0.696
   c-0.597,0.696-0.895,1.691-0.895,2.686c0,0.199,0,0.398,0.099,0.497c0,0.199,0.099,0.398,0.099,0.696
   c0.099,0.199,0.099,0.398,0.199,0.597c0.298,0.597,0.597,1.194,1.094,1.691c0.895,0.895,2.189,1.492,3.581,1.492
   c1.393,0,2.686-0.597,3.581-1.492l0.099-0.099c0.298-0.298,0.497-0.597,0.696-0.895c0.298-0.497,0.497-0.895,0.597-1.492
   c0.099-0.298,0.099-0.696,0.099-0.995C261.151,22.383,261.052,21.985,260.952,21.587z M259.062,23.577h-2.189v2.288l0,0h-1.393
   v-1.194v-0.597v-0.497h-2.189v-0.199v-1.293h1.492h0.696v-0.199v-0.995l0,0v-0.995h0.597h0.597h0.199l0,0v2.089h2.189
   C259.062,21.985,259.062,23.577,259.062,23.577z" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M248.119,38.281c9.252,0,16.812,7.461,16.812,16.713s-7.561,16.812-16.812,16.812
  c-9.252,0-16.713-7.561-16.713-16.812S238.868,38.281,248.119,38.281 M248.119,36.988c-9.948,0-18.006,8.058-18.006,18.006
  S238.171,73,248.119,73c9.948,0,18.006-8.058,18.006-18.006S258.067,36.988,248.119,36.988L248.119,36.988z" />
    <g>
      <polygon fill="#28A9E1" points="236.381,51.612 236.381,57.978 240.559,53.303   " />
      <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M255.381,53.601v-1.99l-4.178,1.592l1.293,1.393C253.292,54.099,254.287,53.701,255.381,53.601z" />
      <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M251.402,55.491l-1.592-1.691l-4.079,1.592l-3.88-1.592l-5.471,6.168v0.398h13.33c0-0.199,0-0.398,0-0.497
   C249.612,58.177,250.308,56.586,251.402,55.491z" />
      <polygon fill="#28A9E1" points="244.936,53.701 245.732,53.9 246.627,53.701 250.208,52.308 255.381,50.318 255.381,48.528 
   236.381,48.528 236.381,50.219 241.454,52.308   " />
      <path fill="#28A9E1" d="M260.952,58.575c-0.099-0.298-0.199-0.597-0.298-0.895c-0.696-1.492-2.189-2.487-3.979-2.686
   c-0.199,0-0.398-0.099-0.597-0.099l0,0c-0.199,0-0.398,0-0.597,0.099c-0.796,0.099-1.492,0.298-2.089,0.696
   c-0.199,0.099-0.398,0.199-0.497,0.398c-0.199,0.099-0.298,0.298-0.497,0.398c-0.199,0.199-0.398,0.398-0.597,0.696
   c-0.597,0.696-0.895,1.691-0.895,2.686c0,0.199,0,0.398,0.099,0.497c0,0.199,0.099,0.398,0.099,0.696
   c0.099,0.199,0.099,0.398,0.199,0.597c0.298,0.597,0.597,1.194,1.094,1.691c0.895,0.895,2.189,1.492,3.581,1.492
   c1.393,0,2.686-0.597,3.581-1.492l0.099-0.099c0.298-0.298,0.497-0.597,0.696-0.895c0.298-0.497,0.497-0.895,0.597-1.492
   c0.099-0.298,0.099-0.696,0.099-0.995C261.151,59.371,261.052,58.973,260.952,58.575z M259.062,60.565h-2.189v2.288l0,0h-1.393
   v-1.194v-0.597v-0.497h-2.189v-0.199v-1.293h1.492h0.696v-0.199v-0.995l0,0v-0.995h0.597h0.597h0.199l0,0v2.089h2.189
   C259.062,58.973,259.062,60.565,259.062,60.565z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```js
$(function() {
$('verify').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
  $(this).toggleClass('verified');
  $.post('/yourUpdateUrl', {
      'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
      'id': ID_01
    },
    function(data) {
      //some sort of update function here
    });
});
});
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
legend {
  font-size: 40px;
}
label {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.verify {
  text-indent: -5000px;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url('social.svg');
  background-position: 0, 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.verify.verified {
  background-position: 20, 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Portfolio A</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label A1</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label A2</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <div id="ID_01">
        <p><a href="" class="verify">verify</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Portfolio B</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label B1</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label B2</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing **px** so it doesn't work.

```
.verify.verified {
  background-position: 20px, 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to put **#** into `href=` attribute of `<a>` element to prevent it loads page again upon you click.

```
<div id="ID_01">
    <p><a href="#" class="verify">verify</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

One more issue is from your Jquery selector: `$('verify')` should be like `$('.verify')`

```
$(function() {
    $('.verify').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
        $(this).toggleClass('verified');

    });
});
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/d2phap/pen/BKMRLX

It's working for me :)

Comment: I fixed that, but the svg background image is not toggling the background positions, I dont know why its not working.....

Comment: @Krystyna: I updated my answer, it's working for me now

Comment: Duong Diew Can we discuss this in chat?

Comment: @Krystyna: One more issue is from your Jquery selector: $('verify') should be like $('.verify')

Comment: I changed that, but my background positioning doesnt change....why wont the blue icon display its white icon below it?

Comment: this is all well and good using seperate svg icon images, but I have a sprite I need to work with..how do I reflect this with a sprite, not individual icons??? thanks for helping me...

Comment: oops sorry, it is the SVG sprite my bad...thanks Phap!

Comment: what sprite do you mean? because your svg file is also a sprite. https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111326/discussion-between-krystyna-and-phap-duong-dieu).

Comment: I am not sure why its not working on my local computer, but it works in codepen...?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$.post('/yourUpdateUrl', {
  'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
  'id': ID_01
}
```

should be:

```
$.post('/yourUpdateUrl', {
  verified: $(this).hasClass('verified'),
  id: ID_01
}
```

Comment: I fixed that, but my problem is that toggling the background positions for the svg icon are not working....Am I missing something in the jquery??

Comment: I didn't know you had fixed that. See my updated answer.

Comment: that doesnt seem to have worked either for toggling the background positions of my CSS... could it be my CSS? the icons have two state backgrounds, one above and one below, but the positioning may be not working?

Comment: Can we discuss this in chat

Comment: First, you need to fix all the code issues brought up in this thread and update the code in your question to reflect those fixes. You also need to run your code with a JavaScript debugger open to ensure that you have zero syntactical bugs in your code. Let's talk after all of that.

Comment: here is a codepen using seperate SVG icons, but I need to use a svg sprite, how do I reflect this in the css? http://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/eZxWgW

Comment: I think I have got it working now...What is your opinion on how I used SVG's like this?

Comment: I'm a fan of using SVG symbols. The nice thing is that you don't need to know the coordinates of the SVG and can apply any CSS transform/fill/foreground color to an icon. Plus, it's a very accessible approach. I strongly recommend this 10-15 minute read: https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111328/discussion-between-krystyna-and-andy-hoffman).